# position relative y absolute no se está ejecutando correctamente, no se adaptan bien los elementos

Tags: html, css, formularios, position

me gustaría saber por qué no se adapta bien mi input submit dentro del input text (el formulario), estoy usando en la propia etiqueta form el position relative y en el input submit position absolute (el cuadrado más grisáceo que tiene un icono de una lupa pero que como comprenderéis no es visible). La cosa es que con un right 0; y top 0; el botón del submit debería adaptarse justo a la derecha y totalmente dentro del propio input de texto, y no es el caso, lo puedo solucionar poniendo el valor de right: -8px; pero creo que no es lo correcto y que de la forma en que os muestro mi código debería de funcionar bien.

He probado a poner el selector del formulario de distintas formas, de igual manera con los inputs, por si tendría algo que ver pero no es el caso. ¿Alguna ayudita?
Un saludo .

```css
.hero .contenido-hero form {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.hero .contenido-hero form input[type="submit"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("../img/lupa.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero .contenido-hero form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hero">
        <div class="contenido-hero contenedor">
                <h2>Aprende algo nuevo</h2>
                <p>Pruebas</p>
                <form action="#" id="busqueda" method="post" class="formulario">
                    <input class="" type="text" placeholder="¿Que te gustaría Aprender?" id="buscador">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit-buscador" class="submit-buscador">
                </form>
        </div>
    </div> <!--#hero-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comportamiento de `position: relative` con `position: absolute` te está funcionando correctamente. Si usas el inspector de elementos de las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador podrás ver que el `<input type="submit">` se posiciona donde debería respecto al `<form>`. El problema lo tienes en otro lado, más concretamente en el `<input type="text">`.

Este está sobrepasando las medidas permitidas por su padre (el `<form>`). Este input tiene un `padding` y un `border` que al decirle que tenga el 100% del tamaño de su padre termina desbordando. Para solucionarlo puedes decir que el `<input type="text">` use a propiedad `box-sizing: border-box` para que el `border` y el `padding` no se sumen al 100% del `width`, si no que estén contenidos por este.

```css
.hero .contenido-hero form {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.hero .contenido-hero form input[type="submit"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("../img/lupa.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero .contenido-hero form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
        <div class="contenido-hero contenedor">
                <h2>Aprende algo nuevo</h2>
                <p>Pruebas</p>
                <form action="#" id="busqueda" method="post" class="formulario">
                    <input class="" type="text" placeholder="¿Que te gustaría Aprender?" id="buscador">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit-buscador" class="submit-buscador">
                </form>
        </div>
    </div> <!--#hero-->
```

Comment: Pues correcto! Muchísimas gracias, yo había descartado el box-sizing: border-box porque en mi CSS arriba del documento que no lo he adjuntado, tenía puesto el selector html{ box-sizing: border-box} y pensaba que con eso ya no tenía que preocuparme del resto de elementos, pero veo que no, que era necesario ponerlo.

Answer (score 0):

HOLA intenta con esto!

```css
.hero .contenido-hero form {
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
  }
  
  .hero .contenido-hero form input[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    /* right: 0; */
    /* top: 0; */
    background-image: url("../img/lupa.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    /* display: block; */
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .hero .contenido-hero form input[type="text"] {
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 3rem;
  }
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Hola, no, no soluciona el problema, y sigo sin encontrarle la lógica al tema.